# Hand Brake Loose

Tags: honda, accord, handbrake, parking-brake

I have a 2008 Honda Accord, today I not that the parking hand brake has no resistance. Its really easy just to lift it up and turn on the parking brakes. Then I check the parking brakes and see that the brakes are stuck to the rotor. So adjusting the hand brake doesn't do anything. It's just been grinding away the brake pad for I don't know how long. Is there something wrong with my parking brake line?

Comment: It sounds as though the brakes themselves need to be adjusted. I'm not sure on the Accord, but some cars have screw adjusters (the main piston part screws in/out) on the caliper. It's a little tricky to deal with sometimes, so may take an experienced hand ... that is if the Accord is one of those types. As far as the cable goes, there may be something going on there as well. Doesn't sound healthy, that's for sure.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the parking brake is siezed on, hence no resistance when pulling the lever.  It looks like these cars use the same calliper to apply both the foot brake and the parking brake.  A common fault with these designs is that the lever on the calliper that the parking brake cable connects to siezes and so the brake doesn't release.

It is sometimes possible to lubricate the lever and work it back and forth the get it moving again but it will only be a temporary fix, a new calliper is really needed.

It should be easy enough to to get to the lever on each rear brake to see if this is the case.  With the parking brake released (make sure you chock the wheels), see if there is no tension on the parking brake cable at the lever.  If this is the case then the lever has siezed.

If the cable is still tight, then your parking brake cable has probably siezed and itself needs replacing.